# how do I Decrement the value using the Max function here?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have been coding in p5.js for a few weeks now, I have gotten stuck on this point of a university project...I can't seem to understand how to decrement the value here with the max function so that the value of the dial eventually doesn't go below 1. I tried using the max function directly with SecureStorageCode_1 = max(SecureStorageCode_1,1) but it doesn't work, the dial always gives 1 when I Preview the code and console.log also shows 1 printed again and again. A few pointers would be helpful here. Thanks

```
    var SecureStorageCode_0;
var SecureStorageCode_1;
var SecureStorageCode_2;
var SecureStorageCode_3;
var SecureStorageCode_4;


function preload()
{
    //IMAGES WILL BE LOADED HERE

}

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(512,512);

    //initialise the variables
    SecureStorageCode_0 = 0;
    SecureStorageCode_1 = 0;
    SecureStorageCode_2 = 0;
    SecureStorageCode_3 = 0;
    SecureStorageCode_4 = 0;

}

///////////////////EVENT HANDLERS///////////////////

//Create event handlers here to open the safe ...
function mouseMoved()
{
    SecureStorageCode_0 = max(3,mouseX)
    SecureStorageCode_1 -=3
    SecureStorageCode_1 = max(1,SecureStorageCode_1)

}

function mousePressed()
{
    SecureStorageCode_2 = min(11,mouseY)
    SecureStorageCode_4 = min(79,mouseX)

}

function keyPressed()
{
 SecureStorageCode_3 += 3
 SecureStorageCode_3 = min(SecureStorageCode_3,12)
}

///////////////DO NOT CHANGE CODE BELOW THIS POINT///////////////////

function draw()
{

    //Draw the safe door
    background(70);
    noStroke();
    fill(29,110,6);
    rect(26,26,width-52,width-52);

    //Draw the combination dials
    push();
    translate(120,170);
    drawDial(140,SecureStorageCode_0, 22);
    pop();

    push();
    translate(120,380);
    drawDial(140,SecureStorageCode_1, 14);
    pop();

    push();
    translate(280,170);
    drawDial(140,SecureStorageCode_2, 14);
    pop();

    push();
    translate(280,380);
    drawDial(140,SecureStorageCode_3, 17);
    pop();

    //Draw the lever
    push();
    translate(width - 125,256);
    drawLever(SecureStorageCode_4);
    pop();


}

function drawDial(diameter,num,maxNum)
{
    //the combination lock

    var r = diameter * 0.5;
    var p = r * 0.6;

    stroke(0);
    fill(255,255,200);
    ellipse(0,0,diameter,diameter);
    fill(100);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(0,0,diameter*0.66,diameter*0.66);
    fill(150,0,0);
    triangle(
        -p * 0.4,-r-p,
        p * 0.4,-r-p,
        0,-r-p/5
    );

    noStroke();

    push();
    var inc = 360/maxNum;

    rotate(radians(-num * inc));
    for(var i = 0; i < maxNum; i++)
    {
        push();
        rotate(radians(i * inc));
        stroke(0);
        line(0,-r*0.66,0,-(r-10));
        noStroke();
        fill(0);
        text(i,0,-(r-10));
        pop();
    }

    pop();
}

function drawLever(rot)
{
    push();
    rotate(radians(-rot))
    stroke(0);
    fill(100);
    rect(-10,0,20,100);
    ellipse(0,0,50,50);
    ellipse(0,100,35,35);
    pop();
}
```

Comment: *"... the dial always gives 1 ..."* So `max` works, because 1 is not below 1. The initial value of `SecureStorageCode_1` is 0 and you only subtract values. Why do you expect `SecureStorageCode_1` to ever be greater than 1? You never add anything to `SecureStorageCode_1`.

Comment: Ah, I see it now, I did change the SecureStorageCode_1 Value to 13 and checked it and it was working but I thought its supposed to somehow work with the value staying at 0 and that's why maybe I was doing something wrong since the dial wouldn't move; in the instructions for this, they haven't told us to change the value of the variable. Thanks for clearing that confusion for me